# Number of teams and matches

Tags: combinatorics

This question has two parts.

1. Given *n* players, how many different teams can be created with at least one and at most *n-1* players?

For example, given the four players A, B, C, and D, the following teams can be created:

```
A B C D AB AC AD BC BD CD ABC ABD ACD BCD
```

I believe this is the power set, with the exception of the set itself and the empty set. The answer should therefore be $2^n-2$.

2. How many different matches can be created between the teams from 1) such that no player meets himself and each team meet only one?

For example, that means team A cannot play against team ACD, and AC cannot play against AD, since A is in both teams. Also, the match A vs B is the same match as B vs A, since teams meet only once. Brute forcing gives the following 25 matches:

```
                        A A A B
            A A A B B C B B C C
    A B C D B C D C D D C D D D
  A| |*|*|*| | | |*|*|*| | | |*|
  B| | |*|*| |*|*| | |*| | |*| |
  C| | | |*|*| |*| |*| | |*| | |
  D| | | | |*|*| |*| | |*| | | |
A B| | | | | | | | | |*| | | | |
A C| | | | | | | | |*| | | | | |
A D| | | | | | | |*| | | | | | |
```

Can someone help me determine the number of such matches in the general case?

Comment: Consider an arbitrary nontrivial subset $S$ of $n$ players. Then, divide it into two nontrivial subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the first question; the answer is $2^n-2$.

The number of matches in the second question can be counted by the number of total players in the match.

If there are $n$ players, then the number of matches involving a total of $k$ players, with $2 \leq k \leq n$, is the number of ways to choose the $k$ players involved, times the number of ways to split the teams, given the $k$ players. This is

$$\binom{n}{k} \left(2^k-2\right)$$

The $2^k-2$ term comes from the fact that the teams are nonempty and not of size $k$ (since a team of size $k$ would make the other team size zero).

This counts every possible match twice. The total number of possible matches $M$ for $n$ players, then, is

$$M= \frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} \left[\binom{n}{k}\left(2^k-2\right)\right]$$

This sum can be written

$$2M = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \left[\binom{n}{k}\left(2^k-2\right)\right] + 1$$

$$2M = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \left[\binom{n}{k}2^k\right] - 2\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}+1$$

The leftmost term is the expansion of $(1+2)^n$ and the middle term is twice the sum of a row of Pascal's triangle, so we get the nice closed form final answer:

$$M = \frac{3^n - 2^{n+1}+1}{2} \qquad \text{possible matches}$$

---

As a check, notice that $n=4$ gives your calculated result: $25$.

Comment: Thank you very much to the both of you! I suppose you were composing your answers at the same time, but I cannot figure out a way to mark both answers as correct. Sorry @bof.

Answer (score 2):

$2^n-2$ is correct for the first question. On to the second question.

First, suppose we are going to pick a "home" team and a "visiting" team. (This will double the number of matches. Since you are not distinguishing between the two sides in a match, we will correct this by dividing by two at the end.)

We have three options for each player: put him on the home team, put him on the visiting team, or neither. So as a first approximation there are $3^n$ matches. But this includes matches where one or both of the teams has no players. There are $2^n$ matches with nobody on the home team, $2^n$ matches with nobody on the visiting team, and $1^n=1$ match with nobody on either team. By the in-and-out principle (also known as the principle of inclusion and exclusion) the number of matches with both teams nonempty is 
$3^n-2^n-2^n+1$ which we have to divide by two to answer the original question. The final answer is
$$\frac{3^n-2^{n+1}+1}2.$$

Comment: I figured out that I double-counted in my answer. It's really cool that our two different methods got the same result! +1